# Trying to compile ncat statically gives me errors on nsock dependency

Tags: visual-c++, compilation, static-linking, netcat

I'm dealing with the following tutorial: https://secwiki.org/w/Nmap/Ncat_Portable but lots of errors are thrown from nsock.

The majority of them are C4430, C2143, and C2238 (I have the IDE in another language so I cannot copy exact messages).

I followed correctly all the steps given from this tutorial and anything seems to work.

I also switch from VS2013 to VS2019, because the v142 build tools were required, but this doesn't seems to do anything new to solve the problem

So can anybody help me with this?